# UK visit visa applying from 2 cities

Tags: visas, uk

We are a family of 5 (myself, husband, daughter and in-laws). My in-laws stay in Delhi and we are in Bangalore. So we are going to apply for UK visit visas separately, from two cities.

1. We haven't mentioned anything about our in-laws accompanying us in the form filled online. Do we need to? By not including it, is there anything harmful to the application? If we have to mention it, how and where to mention that we are going together?
2. Usually my husband transfers some amount of his salary to me or whatever we save. Now I have transferred it back to him to show we can cover our trip costs. Do I need to attach any explanation letter showing the money deposited in his account? How to show that?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should mention who you are travelling with. It's significant information, and UK authorities expect you to give them all relevant information. If there isn't a question on it specifically, there is I believe a space where you can add any other relevant information.
2. You should definitely explain the transfers to your husband's account. However a letter will not be sufficient - you need to include statements from your own accounts. You need to do this anyway, but especially you need to show the transfers coming from your husband's account and to your husband's account. Making that transfer wasn't necessary and probably wasn't helpful. Showing the money in your own account would have been just as good.